# Jcarousel - only first slide shows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jcarousel

So I'm working on a [website](http://h4u.dev.mikare.ee/) where [jcarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) was implemented.

I'm trying to convert the website to responsive and I have a problem with jcarousel plugin.
Problem is: 
The jcarousel below 961px has a media queries both in CSS and in JS, where the width and height of the containers is set in order to fit the screen.
However, only the first slide shows, as the rest are blank.

Could you please tell me, whether it's a JavaScript/jQuery problem or purely CSS?

Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my own problem which was caused by both, CSS and JS.
I simply had to remove the `width:100%` form `#large-banners li` and set its width (with the use of jQuery) to match the width of the parent container.
Apparently, width in pixels allowed the content to be shown.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `width: 100%` (and in media query `width: 1030px;`) set on `#large-banners li`. With these widths they can't float next to each other, instead they will line next under each other.

Comment: Thanks! Just got there, too. I think it's a CSS related problem.